# Strange Ignite Client behavior; ELB Discovery fails, Client scanned subnet and joined another Server Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, ignite

We are using Amazon ELB Based Discovery to connect an Ignite Client to a Server Cluster. The Cluster servers in question came up, and registered themselves to an ELB - however a configuration problem with the cloud-init routine left them w/o a running Ignite session. The Client in question is in the same subnet as this cluster of Servers.

The Client seemed to keep looping through the list on the ELB, finding no viable hosts, which is expected. However, we when deregistered the Servers from the ELB and the list of servers on the ELB reached null, the Client *seemed* to then scan it's local subnet and found another Cluster of servers and attached to them. This was unexpected, as we were using the discoverySpi configured in line with the instructions on https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/amazon-aws#section-amazon-elb-based-discovery

Question: If the list of servers from the AWS ELB is NULL, does the Ignite  Client begin a scan of the subnet? The very second the ELB list went NULL, the Client found and connected to the other Server Cluster in the subnet... the timing is highly suspicious, even though I can't see in the code that it would do this.